# SQL Server recommendation for storing segmented gl account codes in database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I've been tasked with an enhancement to our order system that will require importing segmented GL account codes for assignment on individual line items of an order.

I need to support querying the codes by segment1, segment2, etc in order to load cascading dropdown boxes for assignment by the user. The GL codes will have one or more segments delimited by a character.  An example of a code is "1010.1034001.99.01".

I've loaded several thousand codes into a table for testing where the entire string value exists in one column (delimited by a character).  I've created two variations of functions that return rows where segment1 value is equal to some parameter. The query also supports further querying by providing additional parameters for other segment values.

I intend to support these queries from the table using Entify Framework 6, but used sql functions to get a feel for what the performance may be when the GL account codes are stored in one column.  Performance was not as good as I had hoped.

Does anyone have recommendations on how best to store this data (there may be 200,000 codes).  Do you feel that I can query using EF and expect performant results?

Would a hierarchy organization make more sense for this data?  Our team was hopeful to store the delimited values on one column.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're using SQL Server, you could have a look at the `hierarchyid` type: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677173.aspx

Answer (score 2):

If you would use a table with three columns you could store the values cascading, enabling you to make your queries a lot easier and probably faster. Why would your team hope to store it in one column, what advantage does that have?

if you have

ID
   Code
   ParentCodeId

where ID is a unique key and ParentCodeId is a nullable reference to that unique Id you can split your exaple code as follows:

```
ID  Code     Parent
1   1010     null
2   1034001  1
3   99       2
4   01       3
```

By applying some logic when importing your codes, you can check if a code already exists as a parent on the needed level so you don;t have to repeat them, and that way you coul dget all codes that start with 10100 by selecting on selectiong on parentID 1.

Comment: What advantage does storing it in one column have, well when you don't want to query on individual segments. Oh damn, blast even. :) Have a vote

Comment: My initial thoughts were to store the data as a hierarchy, but teammates were hopeful to store in one column.  I agree that we should consider using a hierarchy after reviewing responses thus far and initial test results for querying the data.  Thanks for the responses.